# How to create AWS Cloudformation Stack from existing API-Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

We have a very complex api-gateway api that has been constructed manually through the console. I would like to create a cloudformation template from this existing api, so it can be managed instead in code.

The "create stack from existing resources" seems to require all of the resources to be pre-defined in a template. However this is exactly the bit I'm trying to avoid. Due to the complexity of the existing api, it would take a very long time to manually work through all of the api resources to create all the definitions in a template.

Is there some way I can have CloudFormation automatically scan through the existing api resources and create the template definitions from it?

Comment: If you are looking to have it managed in code, Instead of doing cloudformation, you should look into [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/). It is a way to create a cloudformation template in actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is popular open-source tool called [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) which can generated CFN templates from existing resources.

Other then `former2` there is nothing (`CloudFormer` is not maintained nor supported by AWS anymore). You would have to manually per-populate entire template before importing resources to CloudFormation.